# Should GRPC net and Azure app service work

Tags: grpc

In this video for .Net 7 and GRPC
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=et_2NBk4N4Y
the say that GRPC should work on azure linux app service.

I have implemented following this guide with no success.
https://github.com/Azure/app-service-linux-docs/blob/master/HowTo/gRPC/use_gRPC_with_dotnet.md

this is my program.cs

```
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    
    // Additional configuration is required to successfully run gRPC on macOS.
    // For instructions on how to configure Kestrel and gRPC clients on macOS, visit     https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2099682
    #if Debug
    builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
    {
    // Setup a HTTP/2 endpoint without TLS.
    options.ListenLocalhost(5253, o => o.Protocols =
        HttpProtocols.Http2);
    });
    #endif
    #if RELEASE
    builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
    {
    options.ListenAnyIP(8080);
    options.ListenAnyIP(5253, listenOptions =>
    {
        listenOptions.Protocols =   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.HttpProtocols.Http2;
    });
    });
   

    #endif
    // Add services to the container.
    builder.Services.AddGrpc();
    builder.Services.AddGrpcReflection();

    var app = builder.Build();

    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    app.MapGrpcService<MobileAppsService>();
    app.MapGrpcReflectionService();
    app.MapGet("/", () => "Communication with gRPC endpoints must be made through a    gRPC client. To learn how to create a client, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2086909");

app.Run();
```

Try test with Postman and only get Error: Received RST_STREAM with code 0

all work run local.

Comment: If you believe this is a bug (an not a problem with your demo), feel free to file an issue at https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet